# What's the best practice to structure exception messages?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, design-patterns

When something goes wrong in your program, you can throw an exception in your code with a  message that describes a problem. Typical example:

```
throw new Exception("Houston we have a problem");
```

Is it a good practice to pass a hardcoded string into an exception constructor? Maybe I should hold all of exception messages in a one place. Please tell me what's the best practice to solve a problem of exception message structuring.

Comment: If lthose exception messages will be shown to the client ocalization is an issue. But use custom exceptions that derive from  `System.Exception`, those types are more meaningful and can be handled separately. You could also construct the message there instead of where you throw it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Tim mentioned in the comments already localization can be a problem if the messages are shown to users.

What my approach on this topic is, and what I really like to suggest is the following.

Try to make it **generic**.

Makea a constants class holding your exception Messages with meaningfull constants names like this:

```
public static const String IN_VARIABLE_MISSING = "An expected value is missing. Please try again";
```

This will give you the ability to actually re-use the exception wherever it is needed. ( Also you only need to edit it at one place and have it updated everywhere ) You can build a wrapper which will handle the localization. But there are so many options for that topic, that I will not elaborate too much.

So you then can throw an exception like this:

```
throw new Exception(IN_VARIABLE_MISSING);
```

If this is software which will be used commercial I would also recommend to write an own Exception which extends the standard Exception.

Why?

You can create an exception that will take your message and an number for example and will automatically build an unique key for you like this:

```
IN-MODULE-NUMBER-IDENTIFICATION
```

You see where that could be handy? Excactly in localization and in faster finding of where it happened and why it happened.

You can modify it to write `IN` at the beginning for Internal errors. `VA` for validation errors. Then the class/project where it happened and then a number or whatever you want.

This system will also give you the ability to use another string for that key depending on the locale the user is using.

**TL;DR** Make it reusable!

Comment: There is no final keyword in C#! Use const instead.

Comment: Sorry coming from Java. will correct it

Comment: Sebastian Richter, Thank you for answer. Is it means that using of class with constants the best way? Why not dictionary, for example?

Comment: Stephen's answer is very good too. Generally it comes down to what you like more and if the work his answer needs is worth it for your application.
My solution just makes the exception message reusable in the first step. while his solution offers a far advanced handling of exceptions. Something possible and neat could also be the combination of both ( the second part of my answer ).
So TL;DR: His answer is the better while mine just proves the point to always make as much as possible reusable. Also using constants means just changing the text once for every occurrence :)

Answer (score 3):

> Is it a good practice to pass a hardcoded string into an exception constructor?

Yes and No.

No in the sense that this code:

```
throw new Exception("Houston we have a problem");
```

is much harder for the caller to deal with. That's because what the exception *means* is identified only by the text of the message; therefore a caller wanting to catch exceptions from your code (for example, so as not to crash but continue running if possible) has to make string comparisons to figure out what the problem was.

e.g.

```
try
{
     someService.DoSomething(sessionId)
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  if (ex.Message.Contains("Houston"))
  {
      //this indicates that someService couldn't connect to the database
  }
  else if(ex.Message.Contains("is on fire"))
  {
      //someService detected that the network is exploded
  }
  else{
  //we can only handle the two previous cases, all else is passed on}
  throw;       
}
```

As you can see this gets messy fast, and if someone changes the text....

Now *this* code, on the other hand:

```
throw new SomethingSpecificWentWrongException(sessionId);
```

where `SomethingSpecificWentWrongException` might look like this:

```
public class SomethingSpecificWentWrongException: Exception
{
   public int SessionId  {get;protected set;}
   public SomethingSpecificWentWrongException(int sessionId): 
     base($"Something specific went horribly wrong with session {sessionId}")
   {
     SessionId=sessionId;
   }
}
```

can easily be handled by the caller:

```
try
{
     someService.DoSomething(sessionId)
}
catch(SomethingSpecificWentWrongException ex)
{
    //do whatever it is you do to recover from this
}
catch(SomethingElseSpecificWentWrongException wex)
{
    //recover from this
}
else
{
 throw;
}
```

You'll notice that there is a hard-coded-ish string here but it's owned by the custom exception class itself, not by the code that decides to throw the exception; this makes a big difference because it means you can guarantee that wherever this exception is used the message is predictable (in terms of logging, etc).
So not only is it easier to reason about, it's a lot more maintainable than hard-coding strings provided by the throwing code.

Comment: Excuse me, maybe I compose my question wrong, but the question is about an exception messages, it isn't about user/custom exceptions. I can pass a hardcoded string to exception constructor or I can use dictionary or something else for exception messages and use dictionary item to pass to exception constructor instead of a hardcoded string. This is my question about.

Comment: @pepeevich - fair point. I was answering the question you asked inside the text- "Is it a good practice to pass a hardcoded string into an exception constructor?". Combining this approach and the one from Nico's answer will probably give you a comprehensive answer. Note that using `Exception` directly is generally not considered a good practice and you really should use custom exceptions :)
If you want to get this reopened perhaps you could rephrase the question to  ask more generally what is a good approach for any class that holds a  string meant to be read by a person.